# Making layertree with multiple nested nodes?

Tags: openlayers-2, boundless-suite

On [Adding subnodes to layermanager?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95923) I asked how to get two levels on a layermanager. The response provided there was what I was needing at that moment. Now, I´ll like to create a little more complex structure in the layer tree. The expected structure is something like:

```
|overlays|
|        |layer1
|        |layer2
|Group1
|      |layer3
|      |layer4
|      |Subroup1
|      |        |layer5
|      |        |layer6
|      |
|      |Subroup2
|              |layer7
|              |layer8
|background
|          |layer9
|          |layer10
```

I found [Adding multiple nested nodes in GeoExt?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41211) doing something similar but to be honest I don’t understand the code, and don’t know how to integrate it into my own code to use it with the suite-sdk.